# Problem using SQLDMO/Vb6 against SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, vb6, sql-server-2000, sqldmo

I have a client, that uses SQLDMO for a portion of a custom application that was written against SQL Server 2000, and they recently upgraded to SQL Server 2008.

The majority of the app still runs fine (doesn't use SQLDMO), but the admin functions which rely on SQLDMO stopped working.

I installed the SQL2005 backward compatibility pack, and now SQLDMO partially works, i.e. I can run "select" type queries, but any "Update" queries fail with the error message:

***to connect to the server you must use SQL Server management studio or sql server management objects (SMO)***

Any thoughts? Should the backward compatibility pack give me ALL the functionality back, or is this a known issue?

BTW: I realize SQLDMO has been deprecated and will go away next release, none-the-less I need to do what I can to solve the problem at hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I figured it out. Not only do you need to apply the "Backward compatibility pack" to the server, you also need to install (and register), the newest SQLDMO.DLL file on each of the client workstations.

Hopefully this save someone else a bit of time someday.